# list of InstancesIds based on specific Tag Key using SSM?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-ssm

Is there is a way to get a list of InstancesIds based on specific Tag Key and Value using SSM Automation Document

Answer (score 0):

it's possible.

Here is the example:

```
  - name: Identify_Instances
    action: 'aws:executeAwsApi'
    outputs:
      - Name: InstanceId
        Selector: $.Reservations..InstanceId
        Type: StringList
    inputs:
      Filters:
        - Name: 'tag:Role'
          Values:
            - ComputeNode
        - Name: 'tag:Instance'
          Values:
            - '{{ Instance_Type }}'
      Service: ec2
      Api: DescribeInstances
```